# How to Inject Dependencies "between" Android Modules with Dagger2 (2.15)

Tags: android, dependency-injection, dagger-2

My current Android project comprises of the following modules

1). Main App

2). Android Module A

3). Android Module B

4). Java Module C

5). Android Module D

I am using `Dagger 2 (v2.15)` as my DI framework.

I am attempting to inject the following dependencies:-

Inject Android Module A instances into the Main App

Inject Java Module C instances into the Main App

Inject Android Module D instances into the Main App

Inject Android Module B instances into Android Module A

Each Module has the following two Dagger related classes/interfaces

```
@Module
public class ModuleX {

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    static ClassX provideClassX() {
        return new ClassXImpl();
    }

}


@Singleton
@Component(modules = {ModuleX.class})
public interface ClassXComponent {


}
```

My Main Application has the following Dagger related classes/interfaces

```
@Module
public abstract class MainActivityModule {
    @ContributesAndroidInjector
    abstract MainActivity contributeMainActivity();

    @ContributesAndroidInjector
    abstract Second contributeSecond();
}


@Singleton
@Component(modules = {
        AndroidInjectionModule.class,
        MainActivityModule.class,
        ModuleA.class,
        ModuleB.class,
        ModuleC.class,
        ModuleD.class})
public interface AppComponent {

    @Component.Builder
    interface Builder {
        @BindsInstance
        Builder application(Application application);

        AppComponent build();
    }

    void inject(MyApplication myApplication);
}
```

This configuration successfully injects all my required dependencies apart from injecting
Android Module B instances into Android Module A. Is it possible for Dagger2 to inject dependencies
"between" modules?

What am I missing to achieve my desired solution?

Comment: Can you elaborate a little on your problem, what is it that you're failing to inject from B to A, are these components? because the way you've configured the app components graph all the modules bindings should be visible to the component tree. Also have you considered sub-components?

Comment: In the end I got this working via the use of sub components

Comment: @Hector can you publish answer with your solution?